# How to stopping moving object?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

i have Tank's class and it's moving when it's called , but this tank doesn;t stopping at all . i want this tank stopping when it;s reached certain position (pos)..

```
 package com.musuh 
 {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.utils.getTimer;

public class Tank extends MovieClip
{
    private var dx:Number; // speed and direction
    private var lastTime:int; // animation time
    private var side:String;
    private var pos:Number;
    private var speed:Number=2;

    public function Tank(side:String, pos:int, altitude:Number)
    {
        this.side =side;
        this.pos = pos;

        if (side == "left") {
            this.x = 20; // start to the left
            dx = speed; // fly left to right
            this.scaleX = 1; // reverse
        } else if (side == "right") {
            this.x = 1200; // start to the right
            dx = -speed; // fly right to left
            this.scaleX = -1; // not reverse
        }
        this.y = altitude; // vertical position

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveTank);
        lastTime = getTimer();

    }

    public function moveTank(event:Event) {
        var timePassed:int = getTimer()-lastTime;
        lastTime += timePassed;

        // move Tank
        this.x += dx*timePassed/1000;
        this.y += 1;

        if (this.x == pos)
        {
            this.x = pos;
        }

    }
}
```

}

**when this.x reaching pos =>> it's doesn't stop !!  , Why ??**

Comment: Your `x` can be more then `pos` , so check it like: `if (this.x >= pos)`

Answer (score 0):

Where do you declare 'pos'?

You should check in your enter frame if it has gone past a certain number so, you would have this, assuming pos has a value:

```
public function moveTank(event:Event) {
        var timePassed:int = getTimer()-lastTime;
        lastTime += timePassed;

        // move Tank
        this.x += dx*timePassed/1000;
        this.y += 1;

        if (this.x > pos)
        {
            this.x = pos;
        }



    }
```

The enter frame checks what happens every frame. You are adding some values to the Tank Object on each frame, for example the tank moves 1 pixel per frame. The if statement checks every frame if the updated position is past the value of the pos variable.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

First add a trace statement after you have the value of this.x in the moveTank()

```
this.x += dx*timePassed/1000;
trace (this.x);
this.y += 1;`
```

You will notice that at the point where the this.x value crosses the pos value, they are not equal.
So your condition for (this.x == pos) fails.
For this reason, you should always check for

```
if (this.x >= pos)
{
   this.x = pos;
}
```

Hope this helps.